# jquery show not working; visible="false " not working

Tags: jquery, .net, html, css

I have an ASPX-Page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#html-Button").click(function() {
                $(".someClass").show();
            });

            $("#<%= btn.ClientID %>").click(function() {
                $(".someClass").show();
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="visibility:hidden" class="someClass">blabla</div>

    <input id="html-Button" type="button" value="html-Button" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="click me" OnClientClick="return false;" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My problems are

- in the `<div>`, the attribute `visible="false"` does not work, I have to use style-attribute
- in the script, `.show()` never works with either button. However, `.hide()` (combined with a visible div) works without problems.

Comment: Can you show the generated, final HTML code as well?

Comment: I believe the div must be `runat=server` in order for the visible attribute to work.

Comment: Ok, without runat=server it never works?

Comment: you need to set `style.visibility='hidden'` or `style.visibility='visible'` in javscript...

Comment: Try using `style="display:none;"` rather than `style="visibility:hidden;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Visible` is an ASP.NET property, you can't apply that to HTML controls unless you add `runat="server"`.

If you want to be able to control the visibility of your div from the server-side, either add `runat="server"` and provide an `ID` with which to reference the element, or use the [ASP.NET Panel control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) which renders as a `div` on the client.

Regarding the visibility problems, change the style of your `div` to `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`, that should do the trick.

jQuery `show()` and `hide()` amend the `display` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suggest. Try not to add the `visibility:hidden` attribute.

You can keep it simple with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someClass").css("display":"none");

    $("#html-Button").click(function() {
        $(".someClass").toggle(); //hides or shows
    });

    $("#<%= btn.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        $(".someClass").toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `display:none` for your DIV's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`.show()` and `.hide()` works with CSS values `display: none` or `display: block`, if you want to mess with visibility, then you should `.css('visibility','hidden')` and stuff...

[Read more @jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)